# Is there a built-in class in the .Net framework that can be used to denote an AnsiString?

Tags: c#, .net, system.data

For dapper I need to build support for passing in AnsiString params.

Databases have both unicode and non-unicode strings, picking the right parameter type is sometimes crucial.

`DbType.String` vs `DbType.AnsiString` for a particular param can heavily effect perf.

In dapper we pass in parameters dynamically, Eg:

```
Query<User>("select * from Users where Name=@Name", new {Name = "name"});
```

I have an internal map that says that if I see `typeof(String)` I know to pass in the param as a `DbType.String`

However, I would like my users to be able to denote that the string should be an AnsiString. Attributes are not supported for anonymous classes, so I need a distinct type for this.

Clearly I can invent one:

```
public class AnsiString 
{
    private readonly string str;
    public AnsiString(string str)
    {
        this.str = str;
    }

    public String Value { get { return str; } }
}
```

Which would give me the clean API:

```
Query<User>("select * from Users where Name=@Name", 
   new {Name = new AnsiString("name")});
```

However, why invent one if such a class exists in System.Data or the BCL.

Is there a type somewhere in the BCL or `System.Data` I could use as a container for `AnsiString`, with similar semantics to the sample above?

Comment: also ... if anyone is wondering why it took over a second to submit questions in the last day, this is the reason :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not such class in the BCL or System.Data, you will have to roll your own.

We went with a custom type to provide more fine-grained customn in the end; this test shows typical usage:

```
public void TestDbString()
{
    var obj = connection.Query("select datalength(@a) as a, datalength(@b) as b, datalength(@c) as c, datalength(@d) as d, datalength(@e) as e, datalength(@f) as f",
        new
        {
            a = new DbString { Value = "abcde", IsFixedLength = true, Length = 10, IsAnsi = true },
            b = new DbString { Value = "abcde", IsFixedLength = true, Length = 10, IsAnsi = false },
            c = new DbString { Value = "abcde", IsFixedLength = false, Length = 10, IsAnsi = true },
            d = new DbString { Value = "abcde", IsFixedLength = false, Length = 10, IsAnsi = false },
            e = new DbString { Value = "abcde", IsAnsi = true },
            f = new DbString { Value = "abcde", IsAnsi = false },
        }).First();
    ((int)obj.a).IsEqualTo(10);
    ((int)obj.b).IsEqualTo(20);
    ((int)obj.c).IsEqualTo(5);
    ((int)obj.d).IsEqualTo(10);
    ((int)obj.e).IsEqualTo(5);
    ((int)obj.f).IsEqualTo(10);
}
```

So; it supports:

- ansi vs unicode
- fixed vs dynamic length
- in the case of dynamic length, explict vs implicit (4000 if the length is <= 4000; "max" otherwise - this keeps the number of query-plans sane)

The type is available inside [dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/).

Comment: And DbString is your own class?

Comment: @zespri - yes, sorry; I'll make that more explicit. Sam was actually asking in the context of "dapper", which is where `DbString` now resides/

Comment: @ Marc Gravell: yes, thank you, I understood the dapper context, it's just that in the question Sam was looking for an existing BCL class, so I wanted to clarify this. Now this is all clear, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use `string` for `DbType.String` and `char[]` for `DbType.AnsiString`.

It will look very similar to your current code:

```
Query<User>("select * from Users where Name=@Name", new {Name = "name".ToCharArray()});
```

Or if you wan use your AnsiString, you can create extension method `.ToAnsiString()`:

```
public static AnsiString( this string s ) { return new AnsiString(s); }
Query<User>("select * from Users where Name=@Name", new {Name = "name".ToAnsiString()});
```

Comment: we looked at this, but ultimately there is nothing particularly ANSI about a `char[]`, and in most cases this is a duplication of the data *anyaway*.